# uploading video to firebase storage in react native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, file-upload, firebase-storage

can someone please tell me how to upload video to firebase storage from image picker in react native .
I have the code for uploading the images but not working for video so if there any example I will be appreciated .
thank in advance .

Comment: What's The Programming Language? Mention The Language You Are Using

Comment: as I mentioned in the title the programming language is JavaScript in react native

Comment: [Link1](https://medium.com/@bilalirfan/react-native-upload-video-on-firebase-417318da0b27) [Link2](https://medium.com/@joananespina/uploading-to-firebase-storage-with-react-native-39f4a500dbcb) This Might Help You

Comment: thank your sir for your attempt to help i appreciate it . I  found the solution

Comment: Glad That It helped  ✌️

Answer (score 0):

```
const uploadUri = your_Video_Link;
        let filename = uploadUri.substring(uploadUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        
        const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function(){
                resolve(xhr.response);
            };
            xhr.onerror = function(){
                reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
            };
            xhr.responseType = "blob";
            xhr.open("GET", uploadUri, true);
            xhr.send(null);
        });

        try {
            await storage().ref('Posts/' + filename).put(blob)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Upload video error = ", e)
        }
```